# Rewrite uri or similar in Akamai

Tags: cdn, akamai

I have an angular + springboot app and would like to use Akamai as our CDN going forward. We have this setup in our current CDN.

If request uri does not contains extension, then rewrite the uri i.e. replace(‘/folder.*/‘ ,’folder/index.html’) and return the request.

Is there something similar that i can set up in Akamai?

Answer (score 1):

Akamai CDN supports rewriting forward path. Simple rewriting removing or adding part of path can be easily implemented with [Modify Outgoing Request Path behavior](https://techdocs.akamai.com/property-mgr/docs/modify-outgoing-req-path). Traffic can even be sent to another server, would that be required.

If you need really custom logic in your path rewrite, you can leverage EdgeWorkers to implement it with your own JavaScript code, invoking [request.route](https://techdocs.akamai.com/edgeworkers/docs/request-object#route) with expected destination.

The cache key should automatically represent the actual object on your servers but you may want to actually test it to confirm it works per your expectations.